# How to save [x, y] in yaml file

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

In .yaml file. I know how to save x, y in

```
world:     

   radius: 20
        x: -70
        y: -30
```

My question is can I save it in the below format

```
world:

        radius: 20
        [-30, -70]
```

Basically, I want to store two float number (x, y) in one line.

I program in c++

Comment: A) Use a YAML library. B) Add the value to your YAML as per the library's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not, not in the way that you describe. You can easily test that by pasting your required output in an online YAML parser (e.g. [this](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) one) or, if you have Python installed, by installing a virtualenv and do¹:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml.cmd
yaml round-trip input.yaml
```

Your required output has, at the top-level, a mapping with key `world`, for which the value starts out with being a mapping (with key `radius` and value `20`) then switches to a flow style sequence: `[-30, -70]`. That is incorrect, you cannot mix mapping key-value pairs with sequences.

There are several ways to correct this. You can do:

```
world:
  radius: 20
  [-30, -70]:
```

which is perfectly fine YAML, the pair `-30, -70` being a key for a value `null` which doesn't need to be made explicit. Please note that some YAML parsers do not support this form, the one I linked to does.

The, IMO, most logical one-line solution:

```
world:
  radius: 20
  [x, y]: [-30, -70]
```

which you can get by compiling and running:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main()
{
   YAML::Emitter out;
   out << YAML::BeginMap;
   out << YAML::Key << "world";
   out << YAML::Value << YAML::BeginMap;
   out << YAML::Key << "radius";
   out << YAML::Value << 20;
   out << YAML::Key << YAML::Flow << YAML::BeginSeq << "x" << "y" << YAML::EndSeq;
   out << YAML::Key << YAML::Flow << YAML::BeginSeq << "-30" << "-70" << YAML::EndSeq;

   std::cout << out.c_str() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Your first YAML example is invalid YAML as well: you should align the keys and not the colons in a mapping:

```
world:     

   radius: 20
   x: -70
   y: -30
```

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of the `ruamel.yaml.cmd` package. Using a local test can be important if your YAML file contains sensitive data.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When emitting a sequence, you can preface it with `YAML::Flow`. From the [documentation](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Emit-YAML#using-manipulators):

```
YAML::Emitter out;
out << YAML::Flow;
out << YAML::BeginSeq << 2 << 3 << 5 << 7 << 11 << YAML::EndSeq;
```

produces

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```